# D3 angular donut arc expand

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible to angularly expand a D3 donut arc from the center?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0biT.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z94b.png)

In these images you can see I've managed to expand the arcs, but because of the way they open the associated images aren't lined up since either only the left or right edge of the arc is expanding, respectively. Is it possible to expand arcs from the middle in D3? The only thing I can think of is somehow manually setting the start and end angles of the arcs but I have no idea how I would do this since I'm pretty new to D3.

Comment: Something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341417)?